# Server Driven UI Mobile with real time data

Tags: swift, mobile, android-jetpack-compose, server-side-rendering

I am working on server driven UI for my Swift app and unable to wrap my head around one thing. I separated the UI and data layer, so the data required for the UI sits on a separate endpoint. I am having trouble with the data sync.

1. Do I re-fetch the data for the whole page when on section receives an update
2. If I sent an update through a web-socket, should I send the data in the message or just a flag to re-fetch data?
3. Would it be possible to conditionally get data from a socket vs http polling? Let's take live location for example, I could ping my server every 10 seconds to get updated data for my UI section or just use the websocket and provide the data in the socket.